# Copy fields between similar classes swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, macos

I have two classes that are same but are present in different places.  One inside framework and one in Normal App classes. I want to copy all the fields between them.

```
class Account {
var prodCode;
var subProdCode;
}
```

Same class inside the framework.

```
class Account {
var prodCode;
var subProdCode;
}
```

I need all fields to be copied from   Object  of 1st class to Object second class.

What is the best and easy way to do in Swift?

Answer (score 0):

Add a method to `MyAccout` to update values of properties in your class, which accepts `FrameworkAccount` as parameter.

```
class MyAccout {
    //...
    func updateValues(account: FrameworkAccount) {
        prodCode    = account.prodCode
        subProdCode = account.subProdCode
    }
}
```